# Remember Scroll Position in very long ListView

Tags: list, flutter

I have a very long list of items being shown in my Flutter app, the list is being populated by an API and the user can opt to refresh the list to get the latest information.

Is there any way to know where in the list the user has scrolled to at any particular time?

Then when the user presses refresh I can then scroll back to the latest place in the list they were looking at?

I trued using this "scrolled position list" but when I scrolled the frame rate was dropping a LOT...down to 20 fps,  I want a nice smooth 60fps if possible.
https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Comment: Update, I have managed to improve the frame rate a LOT by optimising the widget that is in the list itself.  It looks like I can get good performance from the scrollable_positioned_list and still be able to use the extra features it adds to ListView.builder()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your app with `--release` ? Release mode has a better performance than debug mode. And I think you can just use a normal `ListView.builder()` with a `ScrollController` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html Maybe that has better performance than the scrollable List on pub.dev

Comment: Thanks for the comment, see the comment above. ListView.builder() won't allow me to reliably know what data was in the row at the top, this is what I need more than the physical scroll position.

Comment: Cant you just use the list to see in what order the elements are?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) package itself, but I don't think you need it for your implementation.

- First of all, for long lists it is important to use `ListView.builder()` for performance reasons. This will only load the items that are currently visible on your screen. This saves a lot of resources (this is the equivalent of the RecyclerView in Android).
- To get the position of a list, you can save the scroll offset value of the list. You can get this via a `ScrollController`.

Here is my example code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:preferences/preference_service.dart';

class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _prefKey = 'listViewOffset';

  @override
  _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  ScrollController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: PrefService.getDouble(widget.prefKey);
    controller.addListener(() {
      PrefService.setDouble(widget.prefKey, controller.offset);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    throw ListView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return ListTile(title: Text("Position $position"));
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose(); // remove the listeners of our controller
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

To save the offset I use the package [preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/preferences) but you can use the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package as well.

Unfortunately I didn't get the chance to test my code in a finished app, but I hope it does what it should.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This option doesn't really work in my case as I want to know which element in the data list is on top.  If all of the rows had the same height, then this would work, but I can't always guarantee this.  Each time I refresh, the number of items could change, so the physical position isn't what I need, rather than the data in the row.